# Ajax request with jQuery without WP_ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, loop, html5

I try to made a website in full ajax (a html5 website). I use jquery and innerShiv (for ie).

For exemple I want to load  all the content of the "section" tag of a page.
When I use that script, it works perfectly :

```
var link = 'http://ajax.wuiwui.net';
$('#new').load(link + ' #contenu');
```

But when i use this one, I can't find element which aren't into the wordpress loop...

```
$.ajax({
  url: link,
  processData: false,
  success: function(data){
    data = innerShiv(data,false);
    var truc = $(data).find('#contenu');
    $('#new').append(truc);
  }
});
```

For my project I want to load some elements with only one ajax request, so the second script is more intersting.  But it dont work...

Do you know why ?

My project : http:/ajax.wuiwui.net

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: I solved my problem !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem!

In fact, jQuery **can't parse an element at the root** stage. I just wrap all my `body` content **into a `div`**, and it works.

I can also use `filter` function instead of `find`.